# Is it possible to retrieve an image name in an automated test using instruments?

Tags: ios, automated-tests, instruments

I am running a number of automated tests using instruments, and asserting against a number of text fields, however I would like to be able to retrieve an image (file) name to assert the correct image has been populated based on the information on the page, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried test studio for iOS(http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/ios-testing/ios-application-testing.aspx )?
I think it may help you to resolve all sort of automation related problems in iOS.

Comment: I managed to find the answer after some trial and error this weekend `window.mainWindow().images()[0].name()`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the answer after some trial and error this weekend `window.mainWindow().images()[0].name()`